# LINQ Pad- Can you do nested projections? Limiting selected columns while maintaining heirachical grid output style

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, linqpad

I am just new to LINQ and LINQ Pad in particular. What I am hoping to do is to use LINQ Pad to return a heirarchical grid showing multiple nested child tables.
This query basically works, it's showing me the ID of the parent Order record, which is the only field I care to see from that table, as well as the entire list of child HdOrdrItems as a nested table.

```
from o in HdOrdrItems 
orderby o.OrdrItemID
select new {o.OrdrItemID, o.HdInvcLnItems}
```

However, while I am interested in seeing a herarchical display I am not interested in seeing *all* of the columns of the HdOrdrItems table; I would prefer to just display targeted columns. Furthermore, LINQ Pad, when displaying output as HTML, shows creates a hyperlink in the right most column. Given that there are a huge number of columns in the HdOrdrItems table that I am not interested in, this requries a lot of mental filtering and scrolling.

I  realize that I could target specific columns in the HdInvcLnItems tables but I don't know how to do this without the HdInvcLnItems fields being combined at the same level as the parent HdOrdrItems table, resulting in a display that appears more traditionally tabular/relational than heirarchical.

Is there a way to get only selected columns from each table in a table heirarchy? My guess is that the answer is "No, it can't do that."

Also, how would I sort the nested HdInvcLnItems grid by a secondary key, ShipmentLineItemKey?

I'd like to do this as a LINQ *Expression* rather than a program.

[image]

Heirarchical display, what I wanted  (but with all columns)
[image]

Relational Display (not what I wanted, but with only the desired columns)

[image]

This is the result that I get when I try one of the answers:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if you supply the correct foreign key for my var **o.HdOrdrItemsID** in the join line.

The way this works is you need to join the {HdOrdrItems} with the other table {HdInvcLnItems} then do the orderby and then do the select so that the second item is in a new select block.

**I tested this on LINQPAD4 with tables I have in SQL Server 2012 and this works for me.**

```
from o in HdOrdrItems 
    join i in HdInvcLnItems on o.HdOrdrItemsID equals i.OrdrItemID
    orderby o.ordritemid
    select new {o.ordritemid, items = new {o.ShpmntLnItemKey, o.OrdrItemID}}
```

**Revised Answer**

This might be cool

```
from c in Customers
select 
from p in c.Purchases
select new { c.Name, p.Price, p.Description }
```

or

```
from o in HdOrdrItems         
    orderby o.ordritemid
    from i in o.HdInvcLnItems
    select new { o.ordritemid, i.ShpmntLnItemKey, i.OrdrItemID}
```

**Revised Revised Answer**

```
Customers
.OrderBy( x=>x.Name )
.Select ( x => new
{
    x.Name,
    Items = x.Purchases
    .Select( y => new
    {
        y.CustomerID, y.Description
    })
})
```

[image: How about this]

Comment: Shoot. The onbly problem is that the resulting grid is no longer heirarchical, it is relational. for example, I have two rows for the same O.OrdrItemID. When I execute "from Order in HdOrdrItems select new {Order.OrdrItemID, Order.AwpIndCd, Order.HdInvcLnItems}" I get a single row, when expanded, shows multiple child HdInvcLnItems. In the end I guess I didn't get what I really wanted as specified in the Subject "...while maintaining heirachical grid output style"

Comment: See the updated Question with new comments and images

Comment: I'm not understanding.  It gives me a grid inside items column.  You can added as many columns as you want inside items and it displays a table with rows where each row is a column.

Comment: If you want the column headings then you use the fluent syntax as Jonas suggest.  This gives you columns because it joins differently. Maybe because he is calling select twice?  Not sure how to make my syntax yield columns.

Comment: The revised answer doesn't produce what I want. For example, "Mary" should appear in one row. Thanks.

Comment: @ChadD Maybe this is it?

Comment: By Jove, you've got it!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from o in HdOrdrItems 
orderby o.OrdrItemID
select new {o.OrdrItemID, 
            n = new { o.HdInvcLnItems.PropA,o.HdInvcLnItems.PropB} }
```

Here is a whole sample working:

```
public class A {
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    }

public class B {
    public int index;
    public A a = new A();
    }

void Main()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<B> l = new List<B>();
    for (int i=3; i<10 ; i++)
    {
        var b = new B {index=i};
        b.a = new A{X=rnd.Next(1,i), Y=rnd.Next(1,i)};
        l.Add(b);
    }

    l.Dump();
    l.Select(c=> new {c.index, sub = new {c.a.X}}).Dump();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the first block, the C# Express doesn't work. The C# program is interesting, I have to look at it more. It would be nice if the expression worked...

Comment: Did you replace PropA and PropB with the properties you wanted?

Comment: I tired, I got errors if I tried to specify any property after "o.HdInvcLnItems." Selectomng only o.HdInvcLnItems works. Did you try this for any 2 tables in a parent child relationship? If it works for one, it should work with all. Thanks.

Comment: I could take the C# program approach but it's more work and the interative nature is slower, unless there is also a way not to lazy load and get all the orders and chile objects up front. (I'm grasping on a topic that I don't know much about.) I'm hoping for a C# Expression solution.

Comment: Voted up for the 2nd part. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
HdOrdrItems
    .OrderBy(x => x.OrdrItemID)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.OrdrItemID,
        Items = x.HdInvcLnItems
            .Select(y => new { y.ShpmntLnItemKey, y.OrdrItemID })
    });
```

Comment: Good Job,  I checked your answer and it gives Column Headings in the Grid.  I think that is what he wanted!  1+

Comment: Sorry, i'm really new to linq and linq pad and less so with fluent syntax. Can you tell me if this is a C# Expression or Statement?  I'm tryingt o figure out how to execute it. Also, is "o" in your example known/correct? Should I be assigning the result to a var and calling the Dump method (I believe that is a LINQ Pad thing.) Perhaps a working example, or even screenshot of any 2 tables that are in a parent-child relation, would help me. Sorry.

Comment: I dont have linq-pad, but i know linq :)    Fixed code, the o was supposed to be an x.
I strongly recommend learning the more powerful fluent syntax.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like fluent is the way to go. Thanks for your help.